# Java code to fetch HTML source from URL in android not working

Tags: java, android, html, eclipse, url

Please observe the below code i wrote simply to retrieve the page source info of a url. When i press "go!" button, the edittext should display the page source of the url which in this case is https://www.google.com, However for some reason, some exception gets caught and hence when i press "go!" button, i see "error occurred" message in the logcat. I have been trying to troubleshoot this error for 2 days now. Please help me out. Thanks!

```
**//HTMLExtract.java**
package com.htmlextract;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HtmlExtract extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_html_extract);

    final EditText etext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etext);
    final Button gobutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
    final TextView tview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tview);

    gobutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        try{

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line +"\n"); }

        String str = sb.toString();
        tview.setText(str);
        is.close();
        br.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error Occured");
        }


        }
        });
        }




    **//activity_html_extract.xml**
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >


    <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/etext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="https://google.com"/>    

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/gobutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:onClick=""
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="go!"/>


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="hello world" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you set *<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>* in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yea, i did add the internet permission in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
Applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher should perform networking operations on a separate thread from the UI.

The basic tasks involved in connecting to the network are explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer ivkil. I will try it out and let you know